# Responsiveness of Website

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I am rebuilding a  website with a more custom design.  I want this new version to be responsive; however, when I try to shrink the browser window down it only is responsive to a certain point.  What could potentially be the problem?

I'm thinking that it may be something with my skeleton css, but am unsure and am not very knowledgeable in the responsive website design currently (but working at it).

I will include my skeleton css code as well below.

Thanks for all the help.

Here is my html

```
        <body>

    <div id="Banner">



    </div>

    <h1 id="Mission">Creating a Church Unchurched People Love to Attend</h1>

    <div id="Menu">

    </div>


</body>
```

HomeStyle CSS

```
    body
{
    background: rgb(111,111,111);
}

#Banner
{
    width: 100%; /*1200px*/
    height: 800px;
    background: url("../header.jpg") no-repeat 55%;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

CSS

```
/* Resets (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ | v2.0 | 20110126 | License: none (public domain)) */

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block;}body{line-height:1;}ol,ul{list-style:none;}blockquote,q{quotes:none;}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none}

/* Box Model */

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Container */

body {
    /* min-width: (containers) */
    min-width: 1200px;
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    /* width: (containers) */
    width: 1200px;
}

/* Modifiers */

    .container.small {
        /* width: (containers) * 0.75; */
        width: 900px;
    }

    .container.big {
        width: 100%;

        /* max-width: (containers) * 1.25; */
        max-width: 1500px;

        /* min-width: (containers); */
        min-width: 1200px;
    }

/* Grid */

.\31 2u { width: 100% }
.\31 1u { width: 91.6666666667% }
.\31 0u { width: 83.3333333333% }
.\39 u { width: 75% }
.\38 u { width: 66.6666666667% }
.\37 u { width: 58.3333333333% }
.\36 u { width: 50% }
.\35 u { width: 41.6666666667% }
.\34 u { width: 33.3333333333% }
.\33 u { width: 25% }
.\32 u { width: 16.6666666667% }
.\31 u { width: 8.3333333333% }
.\-11u { margin-left: 91.6666666667% }
.\-10u { margin-left: 83.3333333333% }
.\-9u { margin-left: 75% }
.\-8u { margin-left: 66.6666666667% }
.\-7u { margin-left: 58.3333333333% }
.\-6u { margin-left: 50% }
.\-5u { margin-left: 41.6666666667% }
.\-4u { margin-left: 33.3333333333% }
.\-3u { margin-left: 25% }
.\-2u { margin-left: 16.6666666667% }
.\-1u { margin-left: 8.3333333333% }

/* Rows */

    .row > * {
        float: left;
    }

    .row:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
    }

    .row:first-child > * {
        padding-top: 0 !important;
    }

    .row.uniform > * > :first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .row.uniform > * > :last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    /* Normal */

        .row > * {
            /* padding-left: (gutters) */
            padding-left: 40px;
        }

        .row + .row > * {
            /* padding: (gutters) 0 0 (gutters) */
            padding: 40px 0 0 40px;
        }

        .row {
            /* margin-left: -(gutters) */
            margin-left: -40px;
        }

        .row + .row.uniform > * {
            /* padding: (gutters.vertical) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
            padding: 40px 0 0 40px;
        }

    /* Flush */

        .row.flush > * {
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        .row + .row.flush > * {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .row.flush {
            margin-left: 0;
        }

        .row + .row.uniform.flush > * {
            padding: 0;
        }

    /* Quarter */

        .row.quarter > * {
            /* padding-left: (gutters * 0.25) */
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        .row + .row.quarter > * {
            /* padding: (gutters * 0.25) 0 0 (gutters * 0.25) */
            padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
        }

        .row.quarter {
            /* margin-left: -(gutters * 0.25) */
            margin-left: -10px;
        }

        .row + .row.uniform.quarter > * {
            /* padding: (gutters.vertical * 0.25) 0 0 (gutters.vertical * 0.25) */
            padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
        }

    /* Half */

        .row.half > * {
            /* padding-left: (gutters * 0.5) */
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        .row + .row.half > * {
            /* padding: (gutters * 0.5) 0 0 (gutters * 0.5) */
            padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
        }

        .row.half {
            /* margin-left: -(gutters * 0.5) */
            margin-left: -20px;
        }

        .row + .row.uniform.half > * {
            /* padding: (gutters.vertical * 0.5) 0 0 (gutters.vertical * 0.5) */
            padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
        }

    /* One and (a) Half */

        .row.oneandhalf > * {
            /* padding-left: (gutters * 1.5) */
            padding-left: 60px;
        }

        .row + .row.oneandhalf > * {
            /* padding: (gutters * 1.5) 0 0 (gutters * 1.5) */
            padding: 60px 0 0 60px;
        }

        .row.oneandhalf {
            /* margin-left: -(gutters * 1.5) */
            margin-left: -60px;
        }

        .row + .row.uniform.oneandhalf > * {
            /* padding: (gutters.vertical * 1.5) 0 0 (gutters.vertical * 1.5) */
            padding: 60px 0 0 60px;
        }

    /* Double */

        .row.double > * {
            /* padding-left: (gutters * 2) */
            padding-left: 80px;
        }

        .row + .row.double > * {
            /* padding: (gutters * 2) 0 0 (gutters * 2) */
            padding: 80px 0 0 80px;
        }

        .row.double {
            /* margin-left: -(gutters * 2) */
            margin-left: -80px;
        }

        .row + .row.uniform.double > * {
            /* padding: (gutters.vertical * 2) 0 0 (gutters.vertical * 2) */
            padding: 80px 0 0 80px;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `body` tag is restricted to a minimum of 1200px, so if you wondering why it's only "responsive" to a certain point, that may explain it (at least horizontally).  Without some HTML, or a link to look at what you are seeing, it's hard to diagnose.

If you are looking for help in learning how to write responsive HTML/CSS, you could watch [this explanation](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/102-braindump-on-responsive-web-design/) from [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have added the rest of my code to help diagnose the problem